# min() on collections.defaultdict() returns max count

Tags: python, python-2.7, defaultdict

When using `min()` on a defaultdict object, it strangely returns the maximum if used on a dict counting indices of a string.

For example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> defaultdict=collections.defaultdict
>>> x=defaultdict(int)
>>> string="lol I am a lol noob"
>>> for k in string:
    x[k]+=1


>>> x
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, ' ': 5, 'b': 1, 'I': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 4, 'o': 4, 'n': 1})
>>> min(x.items())
(' ', 5)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`items()` returns the items as `(key, value)` tuples.  This means that when they are compared by min (or by anything else), they are compared *first* by key and then by value.  Since `' '` is the "minimum" string (i.e., `' ' < 'a'`, `' ' < 'b'`, etc.), that is what is returned.

You need to tell min to use the second item of the tuple as the comparison key.  Do `min(x.items(), key=lambda a: a[1])`.

Comment: or, if you didn't actually need the key, just `min(x.values())`

Comment: or `min(x, key=x.get)` if you just want the key