# Getting the max from a nested default dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, max, defaultdict

I'm trying to obtain the maximum value from every dictionary in a default dictionary of default dictionaries using Python3.

Dictionary Set Up:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

My iterator runs through the dictionaries and the csv data I'm using just fine, but when I call max, it doesn't necessarily return the max every time.

Example output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 106, 2: 35, 3: 12})
max = (0, 106)

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 131, 1: 649, 2: 338, 3: 348, 4: 276, 5: 150, 6: 138, 7: 89, 8: 54, 9: 22, 10: 5, 11: 2})
max = (0, 131)

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 39, 1: 13, 2: 30, 3: 15, 4: 5, 5: 10, 6: 1, 8: 1})
max = (0, 39)

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 40, 1: 53, 2: 97, 3: 80, 4: 154, 5: 203, 6: 173, 7: 142, 8: 113, 9: 76, 10: 55, 11: 22, 12: 13, 13: 7})
max = (0, 40)
```

So sometimes it's right, but far from perfect.

My approach was informed by the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062566/min-on-collections-defaultdict-returns-max-count) question, but I adapted it to try and make it work for a nested default dictionary. Here's the code I'm using to find the max:

```
for sub_d in d:
    outer_dict = d[sub_d]
    print(max(outer_dict.items(), key=lambda x: outer_dict.get(x, 0)))
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: That's because your `key` function doesn't perform as you expected. It always returns 0, so your `max` function end up choosing the first item.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the values in outer_dict.items(), they are actually consisted of key value tuples, and since these aren't in your dictionary, they all return 0, and hence returns the index 0.

```
max(a.keys(),key = lambda x: a.get(x,0))
```

will get you the index of the max value, and retrieve the value by looking up on the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In

```
max(outer_dict.items(), key=lambda x: outer_dict.get(x, 0))
```

the `outer_dict.items()` call returns an iterator that produces (key, value) tuples of the items in `outer_dict`. So the `key` function gets passed a (key, value) tuple as its `x` argument, and then tries to find that tuple as a key in `outer_dict`, and of course that's not going to succeed, so the `get` call always returns 0.

Instead, we can use a key function that extracts the value from the tuple. eg:

```
nested = {
    'a': {0: 106, 2: 35, 3: 12},
    'b': {0: 131, 1: 649, 2: 338, 3: 348, 4: 276, 5: 150, 6: 138, 7: 89, 
        8: 54, 9: 22, 10: 5, 11: 2},
    'c': {0: 39, 1: 13, 2: 30, 3: 15, 4: 5, 5: 10, 6: 1, 8: 1},
    'd': {0: 40, 1: 53, 2: 97, 3: 80, 4: 154, 5: 203, 6: 173, 7: 142, 
        8: 113, 9: 76, 10: 55, 11: 22, 12: 13, 13: 7},
}

for k, subdict in nested.items():
    print(k, max((t for t in subdict.items()), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

**output**

```
a (0, 106)
b (1, 649)
c (0, 39)
d (5, 203)
```

---

A more efficient alternative to that lambda is to use `itemgetter`. Here's a version that puts the maxima into a dictionary:

```
from operator import itemgetter

nested = {
    'a': {0: 106, 2: 35, 3: 12},
    'b': {0: 131, 1: 649, 2: 338, 3: 348, 4: 276, 5: 150, 6: 138, 7: 89, 
        8: 54, 9: 22, 10: 5, 11: 2},
    'c': {0: 39, 1: 13, 2: 30, 3: 15, 4: 5, 5: 10, 6: 1, 8: 1},
    'd': {0: 40, 1: 53, 2: 97, 3: 80, 4: 154, 5: 203, 6: 173, 7: 142, 
        8: 113, 9: 76, 10: 55, 11: 22, 12: 13, 13: 7},
}

ig1 = itemgetter(1)
maxes = {k: max((t for t in subdict.items()), key=ig1) 
    for k, subdict in nested.items()} 

print(maxes)
```

**output**

```
{'a': (0, 106), 'b': (1, 649), 'c': (0, 39), 'd': (5, 203)}
```

We define `ig1` outside the dictionary comprehension so that we don't call `itemgetter(1)` on every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!